# Best approach for Laravel 5 core structure

Tags: php, structure, laravel-5

So Laravel 5 brings up a new folder structure and I'm trying to work out the best way to manage my custom classes (keeping in mind PhpSpec tests)

Previously I had done something like this

- app

  - Apes (wherein my custom classes were held)
  - models
  - controllers
  - etc

with the new structure should I be trying to segment my classes to fit with the new directory structure? Eg there's a Http folder in app now, should I be adding relevant custom classes to that directory?

- app

  - Http

    - Apes

      - SomeHttpClass
    - Controllers
    - Middleware
  - Providers

    - Apes

      - MyServiceProvider
    - AppServiceProvider.php

I know this is probably a matter of personal preference and so on, but I've been having a little trouble wrapping my head around what the best practice approach is for laying out a fresh new L5 project.

Any recommendations appreciated.

### Update

After tinkering for a while I've settled on an approach which works fine for me (this is a smallish app.

- app

  - Console
  - Handlers
  - Helpers
  - Http

    - Controllers

      - Admin
      - Public
    - Middleware
    - Requests
  - Providers
  - Repositories

    - AbstractDbRepository.php
    - ClientRepositoryInterface.php
    - DbClientRepository.php
    - DbScheduleRepository.php
    - ScheduleRepositoryInterface.php
  - Schedules

    - Exceptions
    - Schedule.php
    - ScheduleCalculator.php
    - ScheduleInputTransformer.php
    - ScheduleTimes.php
  - Traits
  - SimpleModel.php

I decided that if a model was fairly simple I would just leave it in the root of app, but for the more complicated models that required more extensive testing, then I would use the repository pattern.

I've just kept controllers in the original location, but have them sub-divided into admin/public. There's a likelihood that we'll be building a small API for this as well, and I'll probably place everything related to the API in app/Api

Comment: Have a look at this discussion on Reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/2bfyik/what_are_file_structure_best_practices_for/

Comment: I've slowly fallen into a bit of a pattern now which seems to break things up nicely. I'll update the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this stage L5 is still undergoing massive changes. There is no 'best approach' yet to how to do it, and the answer will change over time until L5 is actually released.

The reality is you could do it a number of different ways, and it will all be ok. Taylor has always said to structure an app for how *you* want to it behave - not because someone else told you to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Taylor Otwell has outlined the structure of Userscapes Snappy in a blog post:
http://blog.userscape.com/post/organizing-snappy

Though it is based on Laravel 4.x, it is certainly worth a read.

Also the source code for Laravel.io has a interesting domain-seperated structure:
https://github.com/LaravelIO/laravel.io

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to stick to the standard way of placing controllers, views or models, as most of them needs only one line in one file in the App folder to change. I have done a simple search in files for references to the directories I wanted to change, and quickly found the followings:

The default controller directory is set in the app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

In the same file you can change the path of the routes.php file:

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

To change the path to models you just need to change the references to use the right namespace in other files. For example the User model is refernced in these files:

config/auth.php
config/services.php
database/factories/ModelFactory

Of course you need to change the namespace in all the moved files.